# Can't make the MySQL Client example to work

Tags: ballerina

Ballerina Version: 0.980.1

**Running MySQL as a docker container**

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-workshop-bndes -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootroot -d mysql:latest

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| testdb             |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Copied Code from examples**

[image: ballerina code mysql client example]

Error

```
MacBook-Joao:funcionarios joaoemilio$ ballerina run funcionarios.bal
error: ballerina/runtime:CallFailedException, message: call failed
        at ..<stop>(funcionarios.bal:5)
caused by error
        at ballerina/mysql:stop(endpoint.bal:70)


MacBook-Joao:funcionarios joaoemilio$
```

Comment: Can you include, "allowPublicKeyRetrieval:true" in the dbOptions and check whether you can connect to the database?

Comment: What the `mysql` server version and the `mysql` driver you are using? Btw, please look for balleirna-internal.log file in the directory where you executed ballerina commands.  I've got a similar error and this file says "java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'PDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone." I could fix my error by putting the property `serverTimezone:"UTC"` to dbOptions.

Comment: It doesn't create a log file for this error...

Comment: MacBook-Joao:funcionarios joaoemilio$ ls -ltr
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 joaoemilio  staff  6619 23 Jul 09:35 funcionarios.balx
-rw-r--r--  1 joaoemilio  staff  1999 23 Jul 21:04 funcionarios.bal
MacBook-Joao:funcionarios joaoemilio$

Comment: endpoint mysql:Client testDB {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    name: "testdb",
    username: "root",
    password: "rootroot",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 },
    dbOptions: { useSSL: false, allowPublicKeyRetrieval:true, serverTimezone:"UTC" }
};

Comment: I am using latest release of mysql for this docker image... mysql:latest

Comment: I tried with mysql:5.7 as well
also tried to use jdbc-client example instead... same error

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using a mysql jdbc connector that wasn't working. I downloaded a fresh one and replaced the previous one in /Library//bre/lib 
Now it works fine.

mysql:5.7
connector: mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar

Comment: Good to know it was resolved. May I know what was the driver version you were using previously? Also, if possible could you let me know whether it works with mysql:latest (i.e. mysql 8) after you replaced the connector?